# JS creating array with wildcards

Tags: javascript, arrays, wildcard

So I have a HTML grid where each box is labeled using the following convention. Each box has an ID labeled as row_column. I want to create a method that scans the document and returns an array that contains only the boxes with a specific column number. For example, if I call the function below, it should return an array of boxes that, if I call it with the number 2, would return (1_2, 2_2, 3_2 and 4_2).

```
  function getBoxesByColumn(columnNumber){
        return document.getElementById("?_" + columnNumber);
    }
```

From there, I would use the function to create an array in another function in this way:

```
function test(){
    var boxes = getBoxesByColumn(1);
    console.log(boxes);
```

However, when I call the console, it prints only a null value. Why is that?

EDIT:

Example of my HTML (contains 2 more rows)

```
        <div id = "game_background">

        <!-- Row 1 --> 

        <div id = "row_1" class = "row">

            <div id = "1_1" class = "box_empty">
                <p class = "v"></p>
            </div>

            <div id = "1_2" class = "box_empty">
                <p class = "v"></p>
            </div>

            <div id = "1_3" class = "box_empty">
                <p class = "v"></p>
            </div>

            <div id = "1_4" class = "box_empty">
                <p class = "v"></p>
            </div> 

        </div>

        <!-- Row 2 --> 
        <div id = "row_2" class = "row">

            <div id = "2_1" class = "box_empty">
                <p class = "v"></p>
            </div>

            <div id = "2_2" class = "box_empty">
                <p class = "v"></p>
            </div>

            <div id = "2_3" class = "box_empty">
                <p class = "v"></p>
            </div>

            <div id = "2_4" class = "box_empty">
                <p class = "v"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Alex

Comment: Please click the `<>` button in the editor and provide a [mcve].

Comment: share us your html please

Comment: Edited to add the html

Comment: It's simple enough to do this, but you'd almost certainly be better off giving those child `div`s a class (or using `box_empty`, if it's reliable) and then using `Element#querySelectorAll` on their parent.

Comment: Basically I am trying to recreate the 2048 game. The box_empty class is to control the colouring of the and the v class is the value within each box. Are you suggesting having a second different classe to each box div? What is the point of having a class if they each have a unique value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.querySelectorAll()`, attribute begins with selector, descendant selector `>`, attribute ends with selector

```js
function getBoxesByColumn(columnNumber) {
  return document.querySelectorAll("div[id^=row] > div[id$='" + columnNumber + "']");
}

console.log(getBoxesByColumn(2))
```

```html
<div id="game_background">

  <!-- Row 1 -->

  <div id="row_1" class="row">

    <div id="1_1" class="box_empty">
      <p class="v"></p>
    </div>

    <div id="1_2" class="box_empty">
      <p class="v"></p>
    </div>

    <div id="1_3" class="box_empty">
      <p class="v"></p>
    </div>

    <div id="1_4" class="box_empty">
      <p class="v"></p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Row 2 -->
  <div id="row_2" class="row">

    <div id="2_1" class="box_empty">
      <p class="v"></p>
    </div>

    <div id="2_2" class="box_empty">
      <p class="v"></p>
    </div>

    <div id="2_3" class="box_empty">
      <p class="v"></p>
    </div>

    <div id="2_4" class="box_empty">
      <p class="v"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Just get rid of `div` It's not necessary

Comment: For  all CSS Selector, here is a [**reference**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Note, if expected result is actually an array, pass `.querySelectorAll()` to `Array.from()`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir _"Just get rid of `div` It's not necessary"_ Not necessary, though used for specificity.

Comment: It works! However, as my HTML code shows, there is a div that controls the row values <div id = "row_1" class = "row"> so my log shows an array of the 4 boxes + the row. How can I make sure that my function does not pick up the row?

Comment: @alexp2603 `"div[id $= '_" + columnNumber + "']:not([id ^= 'row'])"` should do! Check this [**link**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). It has a reference of all the CSS SELECTORS!

Comment: @alexp2603 Use attribute begins with selector and descendant selector. See updated post.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is great. Just learned about the very basics selectors I'll make sure I'll read up on the guide.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, what you need to do is find all divs that has the id with the column number and then iterate them to find the given number you want.

```
function getBoxesByColumn(columnNumber){
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); // Get all divs
    var arr = [];
    for(i in elems){ // Iterate all elems
        // Check if element contains the column number
        if(elems[i].id 
        && elems[i].id.indexOf(columnNumber) != -1 
        && elems[i].id.indexOf('row') == -1){
            arr.push(elems[i]) // Push the element to the arr
        }
    }
    return arr; // Return arr
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/34v7v0pw/